# How to clean Python file (numbers, patterns)?

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I have a long text formatted this way:

```
2689 3015 worth n
1095 9183 worth prep
4659 1314 worthwhile a
4503 1394 worthy a
36 272345 would modal
3404 2077 wound n
4789 1263 wound v
3174 2319 wrap v
4257 1508 wrist n
223 41497 write v
1329 7309 writer n
1939 4727 writing n
2483 3390 written a
723 14274 wrong a
5771 930 wrong adv
5544 995 wrong n
5774 929 x-ray n
4424 1426 yacht n
1510 6360 yard n
5354 1056 yarn n
```

My question is: how do I delete all the numbers from such a file and leave only the words that are n, v, a and adv?

When I succeded in removing numbers, adding the lines from a file to a string, I got confusted how to use regex in that  case and leave only the words I desire. The result should be:

```
worth
worthwhile
..
```

so, without the word-type-ending.

Should I try to obtain this by pasting those words into a .txt file?
How would you do that?

Comment: Regular Expressions are very powerful and can be useful in certain situations but I feel like they are unnecessary here. [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you even need regexes here? If the words can't contain spaces, you can just split on whitespace, and keep only the third and fourth results, and `print` only the third, e.g.

```
with open('inputfile.txt') as inf, open('wordsonly.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            word, wordtype = line.split()[2:4]
            if wordtype in ('a', 'n', 'v', 'adv'):
                print(word, file=outf)
```

Comment: made it with
 if wordtype in ('a', 'n', 'v', 'adv'):
                outf.write(word+'\n') thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to capture only those words:

```
\w+(?=\s(?:n|v|a|adv)$)
```

[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jB5iC8/1)

Comment: This doesn't match `x-ray`. `[\w\-]+(?=\s(?:n|v|a|adv)$)`, possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` along with `findall` for finding all unique elements

```
([^\s]+)(?=\s+(?:n|v|a|adv)$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF1kC8/2)**

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'([^\s]+)(?=\s+(?:n|v|a|adv)$)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "2689 3015 worth n\n1095 9183 worth prep\n4659 1314 worthwhile a\n4503 1394 worthy a\n36 272345 would modal\n3404 2077 wound n\n4789 1263 wound v\n3174 2319 wrap v\n4257 1508 wrist n\n223 41497 write v\n1329 7309 writer n\n1939 4727 writing n\n2483 3390 written a\n723 14274 wrong a\n5771 930 wrong adv\n5544 995 wrong n\n5774 929 x-ray n\n4424 1426 yacht n\n1510 6360 yard n\n5354 1056 yarn n"
print(set(re.findall(p, test_str)))
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/RKbNNb)**

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the instances which are not `a,adv,n,v` you can use following regex and replace with an empty string.

**Step 1:**

**Regex:** `^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?!a|n|adv|v).*$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7tF0/3)**

---

**Step 2:**

Now you are left with words having `a,adv,n,v` at the end. You can now replace whole string with only word using capturing group like this.

**Regex:** `^\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(a|n|adv|v)$`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7tF0/1)**